# Equation that defines multi-dimensional polynomial

Tags: multivariable-calculus, polynomials, notation

In two-dimensions a complete n-th degree polynomial is given by
$P_n(x,y) = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\alpha_kx^iy^j \qquad i+j \leq k \qquad (1)$ .

However, now I am dealing with the following two-dimensional polynomials:
[image]

How can I write these polynomials in a convenient form where $x$ is of degree $n$ and $y$ of degree $m$ (preferably in a similar way as Eq. (1), that is, using the summation sign).

I tried:
$P_{nm}(x,y) = p_{00} + p_{10}x + p_{01}y + p_{20}x^2 + p_{11}x y + p_{02}y^2 + \ldots + p_{n0}x^n + p_{0m}y^m$

but this doesn't show that this polynomial doesn't include terms such as $p_{n-1,m-1}x^{n-1}y^{m-1}$ for example. Furthermore, I am currently not using summation signs.

Comment: $\sum_{i=0}^r\sum_{j=0}^sp_{ij}x^iy^j$.

Comment: @Gerry, that is not correct. In your formula poly13 would also contain a p13 term.

Comment: $$\sum_{i\le r,j\le s,i+j\le\max(r,s)}p_{ij}x^iy^j$$

Comment: Is that better?

Comment: That's indeed correct Gerry, thanks!

Comment: It is somewhat beside the point of your question, but something doesn't seem right to me about your definition of $P_n(x,y).$  For a given $k\geq 1$, there are multiple choices of $i$ and $j$ that satisfy $i+j\leq k.$ Which of these is $\alpha_k$ the coefficient of? And for given $i$ and $j$ there could be multiple choices of $k$ that satisfy $i+j\leq k.$ For which of these $k$ is $\alpha_k$ the coefficient of $x^iy^j$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the answer seems to be, $$\sum_{i\le r,\ j\le s,\ i+j\le\max(r,s)}p_{ij}x^iy^j$$

Comment: in case someone else stumbles on this question many years later and wonders how many coefficients such a polynomial would have, the answer is $\frac{(a+1)(a+2) - b(b+1)}{2}$ where $a=max(r,s)$ and $b=|r-s|$